# Pod keeps in terminating on a terminated EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have created a Kubernetes cluster in AWS platform and using DaemonSets to create the Pod.

After an instance is terminated, the corresponding pod is still in `Terminating` states.

Anyone have idea of cleaning up such `Terminating` pod in kubernetes master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always force delete a pod by providing `kubectl delete pod NAME --grace-period=0`.  You can also delete the node (if you don't plan on bringing it back) with `kubectl delete node NAME` and the pods should get cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of end with a terminating pod is:

```
kubectl delete pod -n ${namespace} ${pod} --grace-period=0
```

But you may need to remove finalizers that could be preventing the POD from stoppoing using:

```
kubectl -n ${namespace} patch pod ${pod} -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

If none of that works, you can remove the pod from etcd with etcdctl:

```
# Define variables
ETCDCTL_API=3
certs-path=${HOME}/.certs/e
etcd-cert-path=${certs-path}/etcd.crt
etcd-key-path=${certs-path}/etcd.key
etcd-cacert-path=${certs-path}/etcd.ca
etcd-endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379
namespace=myns
pod=mypod

# Call etcdctl to remove the pod
etcdctl del \
--endpoints=${etcd-endpoints}\
--cert ${etcd-cert-path} \
--key ${etcd-client-key}\
--cacert ${etcd-cacert-path} \
--prefix \
/registry/pods/${namespace}/${pod}
```